# Flutter OnProgressListener for firebase_storage?

Tags: file-upload, flutter, firebase-storage, progress

How can we listen to the progress of a file upload to Firebase Storage in Flutter?

Comment: could you find the way to create progress indicator?

Answer (score 1):

If your upload function is async you can do it like this

```
  StorageUploadTask putFile =
      storage.ref().child("folder/$fileName").putFile(file);
  putFile.future.catchError(onError);

  UploadTaskSnapshot uploadSnapshot = await putFile.future;

  print("file uploaded");
```

After the future resolves, the file is uploaded.

Comment: I'm looking more for a periodic progress percentage. So I can update the ProgressIndicator

Comment: I dont know it can be done. But you can put progress as a spinning circle. CupertinoActivityIndicator

Comment: It can be done in Firebase Storage. Just not sure how with the firebase_storage package.